# Default text for checkable combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, xceed

I'm using the **[Xceed checkable combobox](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox)**. Now I want to display a default text depending on the selected checkboxes in the combobox but I don't know how to do that.

**For example:**

[image]

**The content (red arrow) of the textbox should be:**

- If nothing is selected: "Please select"
- If everything is selected: "All People"
- If one or more are selected: "Specific selection"

**Like:**

[image]

---

**Example-Code:**

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="_checkComboBox"
                          Height="22"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                          SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedNames}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                          Delimiter=", "
                          Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _checkComboBox.DataContext = this;

            Names = new ObservableCollection<People>()
              {
                new People() { Title = "Mikel" },
                new People() { Title = "Tom" },
                new People() { Title = "Jennifer" },
                new People() { Title = "Megan" },
              };

            SelectedNames = new ObservableCollection<People>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<People> Names
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<People> SelectedNames
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class People
    {
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point us to the default style template or pull it out with Right Click->Edit Template, combobox's are usually just a ToggleButton and an ItemsControl of sorts, could throw some triggers at the content part of the ToggleButton and get your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a value converter.

Something like this should work:

XAML:

```
SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedNames, 
                        Converter={StaticResource SelectedNamesConverter}},
                        ConverterParameter={Binding Names}}"
```

C#:

```
public class SelectedNamesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((List<string>)value.length() == 0):
            return "Please select";

        if (((List<string>)value).length() == ((List<string>)parameter).length())
            return "All people";

        return "Specific selection";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Log this as a non-fatal error.  You shouldn't be here!
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        // Alternatively:
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And make names a dependency property:

```
    public static DependencyProperty NamesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Names",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<People>),
        typeof(MainWindow));

    public ObservableCollection<People> Names
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection)GetValue(NamesProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(NamesProperty, value); }
    }
```

Make MainWindow inherit from DependencyObject:

```
public class MainWindow : DependencyObject
```

Comment: I get this error: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: I've tried it but: The name "SetValue" does not exist in the currect context (same with GetValue)

Comment: @Stampy I think MainWindow needs to inherit from DependencyObject to fix that.

Comment: My MainWindow class inherits from PropertyChangedBase because there are some other methods and properties. Therefore I can't inherit the MainWindow Class from DependencyObject. Is there another solution for example using MultiBinding instead of dependency properties?

Comment: @Stampy Is `PropertyChangedBase` from Caliburn?

Comment: No it's not from Caliburn

Comment: Well, whatever object serves as your application's data context really should inherit from DependencyObject.  Otherwise, you can't bind to dependency properties, and that's kind of a big deal in WPF.